# very weird hang at a for loop initialization

Tags: c++, vector, for-loop, iterator

I have a very weird bug that I can't seem to figure out.  I have narrowed it down to a small section of code (unless the compiler is reordering my statements, which I don't believe is true).

```
...
std::cout << "here"<< std::endl;
std::vector<int>::iterator n_iter;
std::vector<int>::iterator l_iter;
std::cout << "here?" << std::endl;
for(n_iter = n.begin(), std::cout << "not here" ; std::cout << "or here" && n_iter < n.end(); n_iter++)
{
    std::cout << "do i get to the n loop?";
    ...
}
```

When I run this, I see the first "here", the second "here?", but I don't get the "not here" or the "or here" output.  And I definitely don't get the "do i get to the n loop?".

The weird thing is that my program is working (it is almost using up an entire cpu core... ), but it doesn't finish, it just hangs.

I've tried using clang++ and g++, and I'm not using any optimizations.  I have the boost library installed (and am using the boost_program_options part of it), along with armadillo.  But I don't think the compiler should be reordering things...

It happens with or without the cout calls inside the for loop declaration, and it doesn't just skip the loop.

The vector "n" has a length of at least 1, and is given by a boost_program_options call.

Any ideas?

Comment: I ran your code and it runs as expected (I get the output `not hereor heredo i get to the n loop?or here`). It's probably something you're doing inside the loop or in the `...` at the top of the code.

Comment: My guess is that it's the `...` that's doing it. It may cout things OK, but you don't see it because it gets into some infinite loop without flushing the output. - For this reason, use `cerr` for debug output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing you should try is to output `std::endl` after each string. This flushes the buffer for the output.

Answer (score 2):

The following program (which has some extra newlines that yours didn't):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> n;
    n.push_back(3);
    n.push_back(3);
    n.push_back(3);

    std::cout << "here"<< std::endl;
    std::vector<int>::iterator n_iter;
    std::vector<int>::iterator l_iter;
    std::cout << "here?" << std::endl;

    for(n_iter = n.begin(), std::cout << "not here\n" ; std::cout << "or here\n" && n_iter < n.end(); n_iter++)
    {
        std::cout << "do i get to the n loop?\n";
    }
}
```

Has the following output:

```
[5:02pm][wlynch@orange /tmp] make foo
g++     foo.cc   -o foo
[5:02pm][wlynch@orange /tmp] ./foo
here
here?
not here
or here
do i get to the n loop?
or here
do i get to the n loop?
or here
do i get to the n loop?
or here
```

This appears to be what you expect, so I'm not sure where you are having issues on your end, but it may be in skipped code.